# Java Script Random Images disabling rollovers and links

Tags: javascript, image, random, hyperlink

I'm hoping this has a simple solution.  I have a JavaScript code that displays random images on each page load. Each image links to its own page, as you see `image1.jpg` goes to `image_1.html`. As for `image3.jpg` I dont have a page for that image.

I want to leave it blank, and when the image displays randomly I dont want any sort of rollover that indicates that it links somewhere. In the JavaScript code below I have designated the area of the JavaScript that I think needs to be modified to obtain what I'm looking for.

Any tips or suggestion will help. Thank You.

```
var imagenumber = 1 ;
var randomnumber = Math.random() ;
var rand1 = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1 ;
images = new Array
images[1] = "assets/image1.jpg"
images[2] = "assets/image2.jpg"
images[3] = "assets/image3.jpg"
images[4] = "assets/image4.jpg"

var image = images[rand1] ;
var linknumber = 1; 
var img1 = Math.round( (linknumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1 ;
links = new Array
links[1] =  "image_1.html" 
links[2] =  "image_2.html" 
links[3] =  "" // <-- what do I place here to NOT have a link?
links[4] =  "image_3.html" 
links[5] =  "image_4.html"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indication of a link will come from the use of an `<a></a>` tag pair around the image, not from the destination of the tag pair's HREF attribute. Suppressing the link with `javascript:void(0);` is a good idea for having the link go nowhere/do nothing, but won't remove the indication that a link exists...unless the javascript that converts a value from the `links` array into an image looks for a blank or other value and uses it as a signal to spit out an `<img>` tag without a surrounding `<a></a>` tag pair.

So, look through your code and figure out where the actual HTML is being generated, and see what must be done to trigger a non-link output. If there is no code to make that happen, you'll need to write it.

Comment: I found this document.write code at the end of the javascript.  And I believe it controls the indication that a link exist.  If I remove the <a href="' + link + '"> from the code then I lose all the links but the images still appear.  Which is good but not exactly what I'm trying to achieve.  I think I need a new document.write code that makes the array look for a blank or other value like you are describing.  - I hope I'm on the right track here.  Thanks!

var link = links[img1];
document.write('<a href="' + link + '"><img src="' + image + '" border="0"></a>') ;

Comment: You are on the right track, yes. Instead of spitting out the anchor tag, you need to make a conditional to choose between spitting out the anchor tag or not spitting it out, depending on whether the value of link is blank or not, like so: if (link === '') { document.write('<img...>'); } else { document.write('<a href.../a>'); } -- I used an ellipse to truncate the HTML being written out, but it should be obvious that the first block is just the image tag, and the second is the anchor tag with image tag inside. Note that the (link === '') is two single quotes, NOT one double quote. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

# will jump you to the top of the page. Try this instead.

```
"javascript:void(0);"
```